# How do I refresh Netbeans workspace?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

In Eclipse, there is something called refresh workspace or F5 that refreshes the files, to make sure to pick-up any files that are changed outside eclipse.

How do i do that in Netbeans ? I am using 6.9.1 for PHP/Java development?

I don't see any refresh nor F5 works?

any hints? any plugins??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Never Mind, found ScanOnDemand plugin and also there is source-->Scan for External Changes menu.

Answer (score 89):

Within `NetBeans`:

```
select "Source" > "Scan for External Changes"
```

this will force the `IDE` to look for changes and "Refresh" the file structure.

I develop `PHP` within `NetBeans` and am frequently creating new files outside of the `IDE`. This does the trick every time and works quickly.

Comment: I am using NetBeans + SourceTree because I dont like the GUI of NetBeans GIT. I thought refresh would help to change file name colors / states. But I had to close project directory root and then refresh otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: @user2917245 Right click on the directory -> Git -> Show changes, should refresh the git state of your files.

Answer (score 45):

I think below is the best Answer to that. While Scan for External Changes takes a while.

Instead.

**Tools->Options->Miscellaneous->Files** and uncheck **Enable-auto-scanning of source.** Then it will give an option like Refresh Folder.

This is cool against scanning the whole project to see changes in one folder.

Comment: In NetBeans 8.0 (RC1), this option is now location in `Tool -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files`.

Comment: Thanks. It is a shame that this option is not activate by default! auto-scanning is not working in my case

Comment: This worked fine for me. Allows quick and easy way to just refresh folders that have had extra files added. My Netbeans never did it automatically.

Comment: @sdespont it's activated by default in NetBeans 8.2

Answer (score 29):

For Netbeans-IDE 7.2 and above

Go To **Tools->Options->Miscellaneous->Files** and uncheck **Enable-auto-scanning of source**. Then it will give an option like Refresh Folder.

You can refresh the folder or whole workspace.

Answer (score 14):

Select "Scan for external changes" from the "Source" menu.

Answer (score 8):

I use netbeans deploying php projects.

**Source**->**Scan for External Changes**

The files in the projects will be refreshed or synchronized with the windows file system.

Answer (score 8):

```
Source -> Scan For External Changes
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I made it like below ,

**Right click on the folder (e.g webpages) --> Refresh**

in my netbeans 6.9

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you're using subversion, if you use an external subversion client you can run "update" in the subversion menu to update the diff highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

The only think that worked for me, is "Synchronization" when right-clicking on the project.

Comment: V-8.2 Right click on folder you want to update with external resources. This will open menu, look for option 'Synchronize'. Once clicked, it will populate two tables in diff view displaying remote changes and local changes(Netbeans platform). Just review changes and hit Synchronize button to update them in netbeans.